# how to avoid memory leaking when calling function in backgroundThread

Tags: objective-c

I have problem with memory leak when i call function in background thread like

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myFunctionName) withObject:nil];

when this function is called in background the following warning
displayed:

```
2009-12-26 16:05:46.777 SimpleGame[11450:99fb] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x63851d0 of class NSURL autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking Stack: (0x305a2e6f 0x30504682 0x305440c1 0x8ca69 0x8cbe0 0x3050a79d 0x3050a338 0x923c4155 0x923c4012)
2009-12-26 16:05:46.800 SimpleGame[11450:99fb] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xe81090 of class NSURLRequest autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking Stack: (0x305a2e6f 0x30504682 0x8ca9b 0x8cbe0 0x3050a79d 0x3050a338 0x923c4155 0x923c4012)
2009-12-26 16:05:46.816 SimpleGame[11450:99fb] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x63cc720 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking Stack: (0x305a2e6f 0x30504682 0x305fed64 0x3058ae69 0x8cadb 0x8cbe0 0x3050a79d 0x3050a338 0x923c4155 0x923c4012)
2009-12-26 16:05:46.819 SimpleGame[11450:99fb] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xe0b480 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking Stack: (0x305a2e6f 0x30504682 0x30603183 0x305fed80 0x3058ae69 0x8cadb 0x8cbe0 0x3050a79d 0x3050a338 0x923c4155 0x923c4012)
2009-12-26 16:05:46.840 SimpleGame[11450:99fb] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x63a2dc0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking Stack: (0x305a2e6f 0x30504682 0x305fedb6 0x3058ae69 0x8cadb 0x8cbe0 0x3050a79d 0x3050a338 0x923c4155 0x923c4012)
2009-12-26 16:05:46.846 SimpleGame[11450:99fb] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x64060b0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking Stack: (0x305a2e6f 0x30504682 0x30560183 0x305fedd2 0x3058ae69 0x8cadb 0x8cbe0 0x3050a79d 0x3050a338 0x923c4155 0x923c4012)
2009-12-26 16:05:46.880 SimpleGame[11450:99fb] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x63b25c0 of class NSThread autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking Stack: (0x305a2e6f 0x30504682 0x30509c04 0x3055fe8e 0x923b589e 0x30560f25 0x30570c41 0x30570ae3 0x30570a67 0x923b589e 0x30570a15 0x305fee2c 0x3058ae69 0x8cadb 0x8cbe0 0x3050a79d 0x3050a338 0x923c4155 0x923c4012)
2009-12-26 16:05:46.911 SimpleGame[11450:99fb] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x6329660 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking Stack: (0x305a2e6f 0x30504682 0x3055fee0 0x923b589e 0x30560f25 0x30570c41 0x30570ae3 0x30570a67 0x923b589e 0x30570a15 0x305fee2c 0x3058ae69 0x8cadb 0x8cbe0 0x3050a79d 0x3050a338 0x923c4155 0x923c4012)
```

I have no idea what to do.so plz someone help me.

Comment: I got the solution.I have to add 

NSAutoreleasePool*pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
/*
 function code
*/
and [pool release] this 2 line in my background function.



<code>
NSAut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each thread should have NSAutoreleaseNoPool created for it.

Answer (score 1):

Girish is right, each thread needs it's own autorelease pool.  Here is an example:

```
- (void)myBackgroundMethod
{
  NSAutoreleasePool*pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  /* Code Body */

  [pool release];
  return;
}
```